# NSButton - set text color in disabled mode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsbutton

For some reason, when my button is disabled, the text color turns white.
I want it to stay black - how can i do that?

Comment: you probably already tried  button.textcolor =[UIColor blackColor]; but just in case

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You can set text, image, colors, fonts, etc. for different status of a button: normal, highlighted, disabled, etc.

You can do that in Interface Builder by changing the state with the dropdown list.

Comment: I can't find this option in IB

Comment: That's not the case for nsbutton colors.

Comment: @ErikSapir - Since you accepted this answer, I assume you found where in IB this is. Can you share with the rest of us?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I mixed up UIButton and NSButton... can Erik Sapir remove the checkmark?

Answer (score 27):

You can subclass NSButtonCell and override a method:

```
- (NSRect)drawTitle:(NSAttributedString *)title withFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    if (![self isEnabled]) {
        return [super drawTitle:[self attributedTitle] withFrame:frame inView:controlView];
    }

    return [super drawTitle:title withFrame:frame inView:controlView];
}
```

In this way, when button is disabled, the text will have the same color of text when button is enabled.

Comment: This seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 7):

**Also check out this**

```
[btnInfo.cell setImageDimsWhenDisabled:NO];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work anymore, macOS Catalina, 10.15.6

Answer (score 2):

You can override a private method in NSButtonCell:

```
- (BOOL)_textDimsWhenDisabled {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)_shouldDrawTextWithDisabledAppearance {
    return NO;
}
```

I filled a radar for a public method: rdar://19218619

Answer (score 1):

Update for swift 4:

```
  override func drawTitle(_ title: NSAttributedString, withFrame frame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) -> NSRect {

    if !self.isEnabled {
        return super.drawTitle(self.attributedTitle, withFrame: frame, in: controlView)
    }

    return super.drawTitle(title, withFrame: frame, in: controlView)
    }
```

This will make text attributes the same as when button is enabled.

Comment: Ladies and gentleman - we have a winner! Only solution from all that works!

Answer (score 1):

In Mojave, any override of draw methods makes it impossible to change the backgroundColor of the NSbutton when highlighted. So I would rather recommend to use

`- (BOOL)_shouldDrawTextWithDisabledAppearance`

for this purpose. If you are using Swift 4, I would do the following in the Bridging header:

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
@interface NSButtonCell (Private)
- (BOOL)_shouldDrawTextWithDisabledAppearance;
@end
```

And in the subclass of NSButtonCell:

```
override func _shouldDrawTextWithDisabledAppearance() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```