# Conditionally Prevent NSButton Action

Tags: macos, appkit, nsbutton

I have a pair of check boxes, NSButton instances, where I want to prevent the user from deselecting both. Either button can be checked, or both, but never should both buttons be unchecked.

How can I intercept the click event and test to see if it is the only button checked? If I set state back to checked in the IBAction, it toggles unchecked, then checked. I don't want this. I just want to ignore the mouse click in this case.

I also do not want it disabled, or at least not to be greyed out. That would confuse the user.

I would think there would be a delegate of sorts like NSTextFieldDelegate with a `shouldChangeState` type method but I haven't seen this anywhere.

This seems like a very basic question, but I couldn't find an answer that satisfied me anywhere.

Comment: From a user experience perspective, the correct approach is to leave it selected, and disable it.  An enabled button that can't be clicked is in clear violation of the HIG, and would be very confusing.

Comment: The other common approach is to use a pop-up menu or radio buttons, with 3 items: "A", "B", "A and B".

Comment: You may be right on the HIG. I thought about that as I was writing the question. I also considered your other idea, I am partial the check boxes as it makes it instantly clear what your options are and feels quicker to toggle.

Comment: I would think checkboxes would be slower to use.  If B is checked and you want (only) A checked, you have to check A, and then uncheck B -- the order is mandated by the invariant.  (Or if you make B visibly active but inoperative, the user might click there a couple times, trying to figure out why the click isn't working, making it even slower for them.)  With radio buttons, you just click once on "A" and you're done.  All states are always visible, and you can get to any of them with just one click.

Comment: Another approach: let the user check and uncheck both checkboxes and make sure at least one is checked before continuing. In this way the user isn't forced to check B before unchecking A. Radio buttons A, B, A and B aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @willeke, you are on to it there. I was thinking I would leave them go ahead allowing to uncheck both. It amounts to a filter setting that would always result in no records shown. Waste of a click, but logical behavior. You give me the idea to just assume if user unchecks the lone selection, check the other. This amounts to the same behavior as ssswift suggested, but with only two buttons.

Comment: @Willeke, I've already tried it out and it works nicely. Actually much better than my original intent. I believe this is how I will go. Of course, none of this answers my actual question.

Comment: "if user unchecks the lone selection, check the other" -- FWIW, this used to be common on pre-OSX systems, even in Apple's software, but I don't think I've seen any programs do this since 2001.  My guess is that it fell out of favor because it doesn't scale, it has invisible behavior, and it leads to the user feeling out of control.

Answer (score 0):

> See my answer under [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53264279/8661770)

Subclass NSButton and override mouseDown function

Sadly by doing this, the `.action` also won't work (you would need to implement a click recognizer manually)

```
class RadioButton: NSButton {
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {}
}
```

If the block is just conditionally then you could do:

```
class RadioButton: NSButton {
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if condition {
            super.mouseDown(event)
        }
    }
}
```